# Deploy UNO Platform macOS app from Windows 10 with VS 2019

Tags: macos, uno-platform

I am running VS 2019 on Windows 10 and am connected to my MacBook Pro which is running VS 2019 as well.  I am able to run iOS phone apps on my Win 10 box via simulator, is there anyway to deploy to my MacBook Pro from Win 10?  Or, how do I get my macOS app on my MacBook?

Answer (score 0):

Uno Platform in relying on Xamarin toolchain to build & deploy applications on Android, iOS and macOS.

When your target is macOS, you need to develop using [Xamarin.Mac](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/mac/get-started/). This version of Xamarin is only available on Mac.

You can use [Visual Studio for Mac](https://platform.uno/docs/articles/get-started-vsmac.html) or
[Rider for Mac](https://platform.uno/docs/articles/get-started-rider.html).

It could be useful to use VNC to remote control your Mac from Windows. Alternatively, you can use [Barrier](https://github.com/debauchee/barrier) to control it from a single keyboard + mouse.

### TL;DR

The short answer is **NO**, you can't compile on Windows and deploy on Mac like what you're doing for macOS.

Comment: Just for clarification does that mean I need to copy my solution over to my Mac and build using VS 2019 for Mac?  Note: just to make sure that everything is working correctly I built a very simple app on my Mac using VS 2019 for Mac and Xcode vers 12.2.